# JQuery Submenu Slide Out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a full page height vertical navigation menu and I want the submenu to slide out from the left menu.

I'd like to know how to convert/modify the jsfiddle in my post so the red area is a main navigation list and the grey area is a sub navigation list (which slides out on hover).

http://jsfiddle.net/1hdtkcpf/

```
$(".slide").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    },
    click: function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.slide') && $('.slide').is('.active')) $('.slide').removeClass('active');
});
```

The red box would be the main navigation and the grey box would be the submenu.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Not sure if I explained/asked very well, sorry. I'd like to know how to convert/modify the jsfiddle in my post so the red area is a main navigation list and the grey area is a sub navigation list (which slides out on hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention as to how your navigation will be constructed so I have used a `ul` to demonstrate one possible way. Hope it helps.

**HTML:**

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="slide"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$("#menu li a").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.slide').addClass('hover');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.slide').removeClass('hover');
  },
  click: function() {
    $('.slide').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

CSS:

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1hdtkcpf/3/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to achieve. :) I am just using a normal <ul> style list. Thank you

Comment: I have an error with "on" function for JQuery (I'm using the latest version), any ideas why? - "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function"

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: No, so it must be a conflict then?

Comment: Found an older version of JQuery underneath the new one... lol (wasn't me!)

Comment: Has that fixed the problem?

Comment: Yes thanks. Only problem is, as soon as you mouseover a link the submenu link shows instantly (without appearing slowly). I think I can add a fadein() function.